# Change the html of span through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net web app in which I am using a span tag

```
<span id = "ptxtAgree" >  <%: data.Agree %></span>
```

and I want to update the span text through javascript and in script I am writing

```
  $("#ptxtAgree").text(msg);
```

If I am writing the empty span then its value is updated but by using this `<%: %>` it is not possible.

Sorry for poor English

regards

Comment: With what value you want to update the span?? what is the msg here .Value of msg

Comment: I am using $.ajax() in which msg is integer value

Comment: Maybe if you try .html(msg)  and not the .text(msg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the html inside the span using jQuery you can use :

```
$("#ptxtAgree").html(msg);
```

If you want to remove everything inside the span you can use:

```
$("#ptxtAgree").empty();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is the span getting updated. How are you calling the ajax. Can you post your code ??

Comment: |I think you are not using it right. What @Sabari said should work. See here http://api.jquery.com/html/